# parse.com error 111, editing field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

i'm trying to update a field on Parse, but i get an error 111: expected map but got string.

here's my code:

```
var Item = Parse.Object.extend("user");
$("#saveNewBudgetAmount").click(function(){
    var newBudget = $("#newBudgetSum").val();
    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    var newItem = new Item();
    var query = new Parse.Query(Item);
    newItem.set("budget",newBudget);
    query.equalTo("user", currentUser);



    newItem.save(null, {
        success: function() {
            location="MainPage.html";
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
```

the field "budget" in the "user" class is a string type so i don't understand what i'm doing wrong.
thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to remove the `var query ...` and `query.equalTo...` lines and add newItem.set('user', currentUser) after the existing `newItem` line.

Comment: well, I've tried, still getting the same result. Error 111: invalid key type for budget, expected map, buy got string

Comment: At the first line, are you sure, you mean `extend("user")` and not `extend("Item")` or something?

Comment: yeah, because the field "budget" is in the user class. now i', getting error 201: missing user password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're just querying for the current user, you can simply use:

```
var newBudget = $("#newBudgetSum").val();

var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
currentUser.set("budget", newBudget);
currentUser.save(null,
{
    success: function(user) {
        alert("new name is: " + user.get("name"));
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("error: " + error.code +" "+error.message);
    }
});
```

Or even better:

```
var newBudget = $("#newBudgetSum").val();

var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
currentUser.save(
    {
    // Set as many properties as you like in this field, 
    // think of it as a JSON object except you don't 
    // have to enclose the values in strings.
    budget : newBudget,
    }, {
    success: function(user) {
        alert("new name is: " + user.get("name"));
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("error: " + error.code +" "+error.message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well got it working by changing my code to this:

```
$("#saveNewBudgetAmount").click(function(){

    var User = Parse.User.extend("User");
    var query = new Parse.Query(User);

    var newBudget = $("#newBudgetSum").val();

    query.equalTo("objectId", Parse.User.current().id);
    query.first({
        success: function (User) {
            User.save(null, {
                success: function (user) {
                    User.set("budget", newBudget);
                    User.save();
                    location = "Mainpage.html";
                }
            });

        }

    });

});
```